# Some math and animation

Tags: math, animation

I have a grass texture:

[image]

I use it in my 2d-game. I want to animate it by code, without any predefined animations.

The grass should interact with wind. So when the wind is stronger, the grass should stoop into need side more.

First version of animation I made using sinusoid function, but such animation is a bit ugly, because the base of the grass moves left/right like all another part of picture. And with sinusoid I'm not able to regulate stoop of the image.

[image]

Any advices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you may get easily by shifting pixels:

[image]

Although probably not very useful for you, here is a Mathematica program:

```
f[l_, sh_] := Module[{c = l, k = (Dimensions@l)[[1]]},
  For[i = 1, i <= k, i++,
   c[[i]] = RotateRight[l[[i]], IntegerPart[(k + 1 - i)/sh]]];
  Return[c];]

b = ArrayPad[ImageData@a, {{40}, {40}, {0}}, {1, 1, 1}];
Export["c:\\anim.gif", 
 {Image@b, Image@f[b, 7],
  Image@f[b, 5], Image@f[b, 3],
  Image@f[b, 5], Image@f[b, 7], Image@b}, "DisplayDurations" -> .3]
```

**Edit**

But you can get a better effect by applying a circular transform:

[image]

```
b = Image@ArrayPad[ImageData@a, {{40, 0}, {40}, {0}}, {1, 1, 1}];
f[image_, angleMult_] := ImageForwardTransformation[image, (
    fi = ArcTan[Abs[#[[2]]/(#[[1]] - .5)]];
    fi1 = angleMult fi (#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2)/2;
    {(1/2 - Sin[fi1] #[[2]] - Cos[fi1]/2 + 
       Cos[fi1] #[[1]]), -Sin[fi1]/2 + Sin[fi1] #[[1]] + 
      Cos[fi1] #[[2]]}) &]
t = Table[f[b, x], {x, 0, .2, .02}];
t1 = Reverse@t;
Export["c:\\anim.gif", Join[t, t1], "DisplayDurations" -> .15];
Import["c:\\anim.gif", "Animation"]
```

Comment: The language isn't important. The result is. Thanks, I'll look at this.

Comment: @belisarius I like Mathematica. I got it to learn something. The only question for second code is how do you load `a` variable (image). I tried: `a = Image['path in system.png']` or `a = Imprt['path.png']`. But first time I got a lot of errors, second time I got an image static, but still a lot of mistakes.

Comment: @Ockonal Copy your image to the clipboard and type in Mma "a=" and then paste. Or equivalent a = Import["c:\\anim.gif"] as in the last line in my code. See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Import.html

Comment: @belisarius in Linux (my OS) copying and pasting image inserts only the address of it. I also tried: `a = Import["that path"]` and got: http://dpaste.com/340830/

Comment: @Ockonal Post it as a question here under the Mathematica tag. There are a very helpful community that surely will help you. I haven't experience with Mma under Linux. Sorry.

Comment: @belisarius Sorry for disturbing you. Now I'm porting code from Mathematica into C++ and Shaders program. As I understand, in Mathematica y/x axises are going as default: Y up, X right. But in shader programm the axises are: Y down, X: right. So, after porting your code I got: http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/2336/res.gif. Can you help me with porting it to another axis-system, please?

Comment: @Ockonal for each axis you have to write down two equations. Xshade= A * Xmath + B. for any two points on the image and then solve for A and B. That is your new coordinate system

Answer (score 0):

You could just shift the rows, so that e.g. every 3rd row is shifted 1px to the right, beginning with the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the texture? When using a billboard you could manipulate the vertices of the billboard and even triangulate the billboard for more control.